# solving linear optimisation in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, octave

i have a simple linear problem defined as:

```
min f(x) such that :A.x <=b
                Aeq.x = beq
                lb<= x <=ub
```

the vector of my variables is :

```
x =[x(1)i;x(2)i;x(3)i;x(4)i;x(5);x(6)] i=1...n
```

i have a difficulty in writing the upper bound constraints defined as follow :

```
 x(1).i <= x(5)
 x(2).i <= x(5)
 x(3).i <= x(6)
```

How can i create the uper bound vector ? should i put all the variables on the left side and write it as inequality constraints?

thanks for helping .

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking... `lb = [1;2;5]; ub = [4;10;12];` would be used for the constraints 1<= x1 <=4, 2<=x2 <=10, 5<=x3<=12

Comment: i'm asking about how to write lb and ub for my case: 0<=x(1).i <= x(5), 0<= x(2).i <= x(5) , 0 <= x(3).i <= x(6). such that x(5) ,x(3) are also  problem variables ? should i write lb=zeros(4*n+2,1)  and consider upper bounds as inequality constraints ?

Comment: What is this .i stuff? what is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper bound constraint `ub` is for when the upper bound are *numbers* (more precisely a vector of doubles). `ub` is *not* for generalized, linear inequality constraints!

I'm going to ignore your .i notation because I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Your constraints: `x1 <= x5`, `x2 <= x5`, `x3 <= x6` can be written in matrix form:

```
[1  0  0  0 -1  0      [x1        [0
 0  1  0  0 -1  0   *   x2   <=    0
 0  0  1  0  0 -1]      x3         0];
                        x4
                        x5
                        x6
```

Hence to use several of the Matlab solvers you would do:

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0, -1,  0;         
     0, 1, 0, 0, -1,  0;
     0, 0, 1, 0,  0, -1];
b = zeros(3, 1);
```

Now your constraints are written in the form of A*x <= b